# Regular Expression to match member variables

Tags: c++, regex, emacs, font-lock

I am trying to improve emacs c++-mode syntax highlighting and need to find a regular expression to match member variables in the code.

[image: atom's syntax highlighting]

What I want to match with the regular expression is the red keywords in the screenshot and not the blue ones.

To find function calls(blue ones), I am using the expression `([a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)+[(]`

I want to modify this so that if there is any parentheses after the keyword, it does not match.

Comment: Some regular expression engines support negative lookahead syntax, as in `a(?!\()` (matches character `a` but only if it's not followed by an opening paren). See if yours does.

Comment: Emacs Wiki says it does not support. Is it possible with another method, using logical operations etc.?

Comment: Are you trying to do this via `font-lock-keywords`? Either way, show us some code -- as you've ascertained, elisp regexps do not have zero-width assertions of that kind, so you'll need to write some elisp to do this, so it'll help to know what you're trying at the moment.

Comment: btw, those commas in your character alternatives are just adding a comma to the set of matched characters. Syntax class matching would be a better idea. I'm not even sure what your `FOO+*` is matching. I'm guessing that's zero-or-more matches of one-or-more FOOs, which makes the `+` redundant. Your grouping parentheses aren't escaped, and there's no need for a character alternative in `[(]`.

Comment: Could you just check for the function call first, then, if it isn't a function call, check for the member variable name?

Comment: @phils +* was a typing error corrected it. That regex is used to match function calls and function calls only. So the parenthesis at the end lets me do this. I am trying to achieve this using font-lock-keywords.
`(font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
   '(("\\([a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z1-9_]*\\)+[(]" 1 font-lock-function-name-face append)))`
Using the above code, it gets extremely slow to write something that does not match for example writing into a string literal or writing a comment gets extremely slow and sometimes emacs freezes.

Comment: Btw, I know neither regex nor elisp. But I could write some elisp, I believe. Could you please elaborate more on syntax class matching?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes, appending the regexp to the keyword list should do exactly what I want. No need for negative lookahead because function calls will already be higlighted. The only problem is emacs gets extremely slow doing so, probably caused by my problematic regexps.

Comment: If you add something like `\\_<` to the beginning of the regexp things will probably run faster, this construct ensures that the rest only when when at the beginning of a symbol. (Your current regexp will match "member", "ember", "mber", "ber", "er", and "r"...)

Comment: If you haven't seen it already, you can use my font-lock keyword debugger https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio to single step your keywords when highlighting actual source code.

Comment: I guess `1-9` should be `0-9`.

Comment: Why do you use `append`? If you drop it, font-lock will not apply your face to strings and comments. If you plan to keep it, you could wrap your regexp in lisp code explicitly checking when you are in a string or comment.

Comment: @Lindydancer My regexp should not fontify comments or strings. That's why I used append. However, although I appended it to the keywords, it freezes when I try to type into a string literal quickly. Also the overall performance is very bad. I do not know how to solve the problem. For me, the regexp I use looks very simple and should not run slow. Is there anything else I am missing? Btw, adding `\\_<` did not affect the performance, maybe did negatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do what you want.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'c++-mode
 '(("\\(\\_<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\_>\\)[(]" 1 font-lock-function-name-face)
   ("\\.\\(\\_<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\_>\\)" 1 font-lock-variable-name-face)))
```

I modified your first regexp slightly in an attempt to address your performance issues (see below for explanation).  The second regexp just exchanges the trailing parenthesis for a leading period; we're relying on the ordering of the two regexps to handle method calls which would match both.

As others have mentioned, your performance issues are probably due to a regexp that can match in too many ways.  Anchoring with the symbol-boundary markers `\_<` and `\_>` should help.  I was also troubled by the adjacent `+` and `*` groups on non-disjoint character sets, but I don't know if this was actually a problem.

Since you don't appear to want highlighting in strings and comments, you should leave `append` off.  If you wanted string and comment highlighting you would use `prepend`, while `append` would only be useful if you were using a face that sets a property that your string or comment faces didn't and you wanted to combine the two.  To see what I'm talking about, try replacing `font-lock-function-name-face` with `'hi-yellow`.  (The quote is relevant here, since the highlight faces don't have variable aliases like the font lock faces.)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I had already solved the issue before your answer without using `_<' . `+` probably was the main problem. I will try with `_<` to see how it affects performance. For the `append`, you're absolutely right.  I need to add, I think, both keywords can be used for all c family languages: c,c++,java. To do that, one can add a hook to `'c-mode-common-hook`.

Comment: As I said using `+` was the main problem. But thanks again for the extra `\_<`.